# Haskell Typeclass Type Constraints and Deduction

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've been running through the "Learn You a Haskell" book, and I'm trying to wrap my head around Haskell Type Classes. As practice, I'm trying to create a simple vector type class. The following snippet of code has been giving me some grief (resulting in my first post to StackOverflow):

```
data Vec2 a = Vec2 (a,a) deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

class Vector a where
    (<*) :: (Num b) => a -> b -> a

instance (Num a) => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    Vec2 (x,y) <* a = Vec2 (a*x, a*y)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Could not deduce (a~b) from the context (Num a) or from (Num b) bound by the type signature for
    <* :: Num b => Vec2 a -> b -> Vec2 a
```

It seems like the `Num` being specified in the typeclass should supply the type of `a`, and `Num a` spefication in the instance should supply the type of `x` and `y`, so why is it complaining? What misconception do I have about this code?

Comment: Hint, b is universally quantified.

Comment: Hint, `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, because b is universally quanitfied, compiler is not able to deduce `a~b` when you use `*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. But when you are actually trying to use `*`, you are actually multiplying two unrelated types having `Num` instances and the compiler is not able to infer that they are same.

To explain it more clearly look at the type of `<*` and the universal quantification of `b`

```
(<*) :: (Num b) => a -> b -> a
```

What you are saying here is, give me any type having `Num` instance and I will be able to multiply that with my vector, but what you want to say is something different.

You need to some how say that `a` in the type `Vec2 a` is same as `b` in the type `(<*) :: Num b => a -> b -> a`, only then you can multiply them together. Here is a solution using typefamilies to ensure this constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data Vec2 a = Vec2 (a,a) deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

class (Num (VectorOf a)) => Vector a where
    type VectorOf a :: *
    (<*) :: a -> (VectorOf a) -> a

instance (Num a) => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    type VectorOf (Vec2 a) = a
    Vec2 (x,y) <* a = Vec2 (a*x, a*y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't verify that both of the `Num` instances involved are actually the same type.  They're each `Num` instances, sure, but what is also required is that they must be the *same* instance.

Otherwise, you could write something like this:

```
Vec2 (1 :: Double, 2 :: Double) <* (3 :: Int)
```

which doesn't fly when it comes time to do, ex: `(1 :: Double) * (3 :: Int)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `(*)` has the type `(Num a) => a -> a -> a` rather than `(Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> a` that complier expected.

I'm not familiar with Haskell's number conversion but I have a limited workaround, given the second argument is an instance of `Integral`.

```
data Vec2 a = Vec2 (a,a) deriving (Show, Eq, Read)    

class Vector a where
    (<*) :: (Integral b) => a -> b -> a

instance (Num a) => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    Vec2 (x,y) <* a = Vec2 (x*b, y*b)
        where b = fromIntegral a
```

because `fromIntegral` has type `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, it can convert the second argument of `*` as needed.

Comment: What about multiplying with say `4.2`?

Comment: @Satvik it works only when the Vec2 was multipled with Integrals, I want to have a function of type `(Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> a` in place of `*` but I have no idea how to implement it.